# Array of string to ListViewItemCollection

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, linq, listview

How I can add in one step an Array of string into a Listview for example using LINQ or Casting methods?

This is what I've tried but does not work:

```
ListView1.Items.AddRange("a b c d e f".Split(" ").ToArray _
.Select(Function(x) New ListViewItem(x)))
```

UPDATE:

Another try, does not work:

```
ListView1.Items.AddRange( _
    New ListView.ListViewItemCollection( _
    {"Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"} _
   .Select(Function(x) New ListViewItem(x))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AddRange` expects an array but the `Select` function returns an `IEnumerable`. So you just have to add `ToArray` to the end of the expression.
Since `Split` returns a string array there is no need to add a call to `ToArray` there.

This will do the job:

```
ListView1.Items.AddRange("a b c d e f".Split(" "c) _
                                      .Select(Function(x) New ListViewItem(x)) _
                                      .ToArray)
```

Comment: @DanielNeel: No it can't. `Select` expects an argument of type `Func(Of String, TResult)`. `New ListViewItem(x)` is of type `ListViewItem`. Besides that `x` is not defined.

Comment: Whoops, you're correct @pescolino. Should have looked at that more closely before posting - deleting my comment to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have to set the first column with 'Items.Add' and the rest of the columns with 'SubItems.AddRange'. This is the code I use to accomplish that:

```
string[] arr = "column1|column2|column3".Split('|');
ListView1.Items.Add(arr[0]).SubItems.AddRange(new string[] { arr[1], arr[2] });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ListView1.Items.AddRange("a b c d e f".Split(" ".ToCharArray()))
```

The above should be the correct syntax in order to add those characters as the list

**EDIT**
Think I missed the ListViewItem collection out

```
ListView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem("a b c d e f".Split(" ".ToCharArray())))
```

Comment: Thanks but any of the two codes works, both throws exceptions... but also I've asked for a string array, not for a characters array, the character values I wrote were only to give an example, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Done!

I hope this helps someone else:

```
  ' Set the Array content
  Dim Items As String() = "ABC DEF GHI JKL".Split

  ' Add them in one step
  ListView1.Items.AddRange(Items.Select(Function(x) New ListViewItem(x)).ToArray)
```